# What is the use case of the `execute` extrinsic inside the collective pallet?

Tags: pallet-collective

IIUC the `execute` extrinsic allows a member of the collective to execute a call with the `Member` origin, but at that point why wouldn't the caller directly execute the call? I couldn't find any use cases of this inside the substrate codebase and there aren't any tests inside the pallet that use this extrinsic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows the "beauty" of FRAME ;) Jokes aside, you could use this to configure a pallet to only allow members of some collective to issue calls.
The collective pallet already provides you with [`EnsureMember`](https://docs.rs/pallet-collective/latest/pallet_collective/struct.EnsureMember.html) which implements [`EnsureOrigin`](https://docs.rs/frame-support/latest/frame_support/traits/trait.EnsureOrigin.html) that ensures that only members of the collective are allowed to issue calls.